# Accessing local wireless network by name

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have set up local wireless network on my notebook. I can connect to that network from my iphone and browse files in /var/www/ by typing the IP (10.42.0.1) in Safari. How can I give name for 10.42.0.1, I want to type specific name instead of IP in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually add DNS entry into iPhone (I am not sure, if this is even possible) or another option is to run DNS server in your own network with this custom entry.